# Django which template to extends with if block

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two distincts template which must be extended in three diffrents page.
Is there a solution to extends a template with `if block`?
I  tried this without success.

```
{% if 'project' in request.get_full_path %}
  {% extends 'index.html' %}

{% elif 'network' in request.get_full_path %}
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% elif 'zoneset' in request.get_full_path %}
  {% extends 'base.html' %}

{% endif %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %} Network {% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="card card-body">
      <h6>Update</h6>
      <form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
          {{form|crispy}}
        <input type="submit" name="" value="Update">
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you work with template inheritance, [**`{% extends … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#extends) should be the first template tag. You can not use an `{% if … %}` block, nor is it a good idea to detect the parent based on the full path of the request.

You can do this in the view, and work with:

```
def my_view(request):
    context = { 'parent': 'index.html' }
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context)
```

and then in the template use:

```
{% extends parent %}
…
```

Comment: How can I include the other template base.html?

Comment: @aba2s: you render it with a different context, so `{ 'parent': 'base.html' }`).